# Why is -webkit-box-flex not being overridden in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, flexbox

**TL;DR:** -webkit-box-flex is not overridden by flex and flex-grow properties. Question: Why? *(Run code snippet to see the prove.)*

CodePen (works even in Firefox): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWOrqN

**Long version:**

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="STYLE2 style8 SPECIAL">
    <div class="style1 STYLE2 style3 style4 style5 style7" style="flex: 1 1 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 1">
        <div class="something">...</div>
        <div class="style1 STYLE2 style3 style4 style5 style6" style="flex: 400 400 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 400;">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .style1 { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 0em;
  }
  .STYLE2 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .style3 {
    position: relative;
  }
  .style4 {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .style5 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .style6 {
    height: 0;
  }
  .style7 {
    width: 0;
  }
  .style8 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
</style>
```

(I don't have much opportunity to change the structure of the code or css, so I just put it as it is)

And it will give this in Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 beta (64-bit) on Windows 8.1:

[image]

And if I add only one line of css anywhere in the CSS (before or after other mentioned styles, or even just add it to .STYLE2 at the very beginning):

```
.SPECIAL {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
```

It becomes this:

[image]

WHY???

What is -webkit-box-flex doing in Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 beta (64-bit) (and the same case in FIREFOX 52.0.1!!!) that is more important than flex: 1 1 auto? Why is it not overriden with flex and flex-grow properties? I thought in Chrome 58 I can get rid of -webkit-box-flex. Is it a bug or a feature? Webkit-box-flex is not the same thing as flex-grow?

Here is the code snippet with the same type of behaviour to illustrate the question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test webkit-box-flex</title>
  <style type="text/css">
.style3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 0em;
    flex: 1 1 0em;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}
  .style2 {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;  /* This is the line that changes the whole view */
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #bababa;
    padding: 0;
}
.style1, .style1.style2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.style4 {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1.5em;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.style3 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.style2.style5, .style2.style7 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.style2.style5, .style2.style1 {
    border: none;
}
.style2.style5>.style3.Fixed, .style2.style1>.style3.Fixed {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.style6 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 2em;
    padding-left: .3em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    color: #333;
}
.style2.style5, .style2.style7 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.style2.style5>.style3.Flex {
    height: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 50px; bottom: 0px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: -moz-box; display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; -moz-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -ms-flex-direction: column;">
        <div id="style2" class="style2 style1">
          <div class="style4 style4Left">
            <div class="style4ButtonsLeft" style="left: -60.5156px;">
              <div class="style4Button key4460">Lipsum</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="style3 style2 Fixed style5" flexwidth="300" style="flex: 0 0 300px; -webkit-box-flex: 0; display: none;">
            <div class="style6">
              <div>Library</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="style3 style2 Flex style5" flexwidth="1" style="flex: 1 1 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 1;">
          <div class="style6">
          <div>Lipsum2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="style3 Flex" flexwidth="2" style="flex: 2 2 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 2;">
          <div class="style6">
          <div>Properties</div>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          <p>Select a component to see its properties.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="style3 style2 Flex style5" flexwidth="1" style="flex: 1 1 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 1;">
          <div class="style6">
          <div>Lipsum2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="style3 style2 Flex style7" flexwidth="400" style="flex: 400 400 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 400;">
          <div class="style6">
          <div>Lipsum5</div>
          </div>
            <div class="style6 tabs">
            <div class="style6 selected">
            <div>Lipsum4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style6">
            <div>View</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style6">
            <div>Data</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style6">
            <div>Servers</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="style3 Flex" flexwidth="400" style="flex: 400 400 0px; -webkit-box-flex: 400;">
            <div style="display: block;">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            Some content goes here
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael_B If I could up vote once more I would have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-webkit-box-flex: 1` is having an impact on your layout because it is being applied to a flex item who's parent ***does not*** have `display: flex`.

The parent of `.style2` has multiple prefixed rules for a flex container. But the standard, unprefixed (W3C) version – `display: flex` – is missing!

*Your code:*

[image]

Therefore, the browser is recognizing `display: -webkit-box` as the prevailing rule on the container, which results in `-webkit-box-flex: 1` being the prevailing rule on the child.

[image]

Standard flex properties on the child, such as `flex-grow` and `flex`, are not recognized and, therefore, ignored.

Once you add `display: flex` to the container, `-webkit-box-flex: 1` no longer has an effect and can be safely removed.

[image]

Also, as seen in developer tools, it appears that when Firefox sees a `-webkit-` property, it automatically adds the `-moz-` version.

[image]